# Charged Particle Trajectories in Magnetic Fields

Tags: python-3.x

I've been trying to plot the trajectories of charged particles in the field of a magnetic dipole in an attempt to give a rough pictorial representation of the northern lights.  While the spiraling appears to be what I would have expected, it looks as though the spirals start out tight and get wider, as if the particles are somehow gaining energy.  I'm not sure what the issue is in the code, and I would appreciate any pointers!

Shown below are the contents of the main loop (initial conditions and all were set outside).

```
# polar to cartesian
r = np.sqrt(X*X+Y*Y+Z*Z)
theta = np.arccos(Z/r)
phi = np.arctan(Y/X)

# magnetic field/mass
Bx = K*(1/(r**(3)))*(2*np.cos(theta)*np.sin(theta)*np.cos(phi)+np.sin(theta)*np.cos(theta)*np.cos(phi))
By = K*(1/(r**(3)))*(2*np.cos(theta)*np.sin(theta)*np.sin(phi)+np.sin(theta)*np.cos(theta)*np.sin(phi))
Bz = K*(1/(r**(3)))*(2*np.cos(theta)*np.cos(theta)-np.sin(theta)*np.sin(theta))

# acceleration components
ax = (1.6*10**(-19))*(vy*Bz - vz*By)
ay = (1.6*10**(-19))*(vz*Bx - vx*Bz)
az = (1.6*10**(-19))*(vx*By - vy*Bx)

# velocity components
vx = vx + ax*dt
vy = vy + ay*dt
vz = vz + az*dt

# position components
X = X + vx*dt + 0.5*ax*dt*dt
Y = Y + vy*dt + 0.5*ay*dt*dt
Z = Z + vz*dt + 0.5*az*dt*dt

# add position values to position vectors
x1.append(X)
y1.append(Y)
z1.append(Z)
```

And a figure of what the current trajectories look like (the particles are starting out at the top in tighter spirals before gradually increasing their radii):

[figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ7lv.png)

(I'm using Python 3.6 for this project)

Comment: "it looks as though the spirals start out tight and get wider, as if the particles are somehow gaining energy" – isn't that the exact purpose of the `acceleration components`? Although it is a very small value (*G*?)... still, does it look the same without those lines?

Comment: I thought the acceleration should contribute to faster and faster cycles (acting more centripetally the closer to the poles the particles travel), but producing tighter circles (like in this figure: http://www.kshitij-iitjee.com/Study/Physics/Part6/Chapter29/49.jpg).  In this code, the acceleration is actually strictly from the Lorentz force, as gravitational effects appeared to be negligible in comparison (since the particles are extremely small).  So, if I remove those lines, the particles don't interact with the magnetic filed at all

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So this snip of code should accurately describe the spiral, according to your formulae, correct? But I don't think we can check that - or verify if we have a suggestion for a fix - without knowing what formulae it uses, and the proper set-up routines to run your code and get your current result.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  After much troubleshooting, I learned that the problem appears to be a timestep that's just too large (dramatically too large).  I made the timestep 1000 times smaller and it no longer blows up (rather acts almost as if it were in a uniform field, which is to be expected since the distance between the particles and the poles of the magnetic dipole is quite large).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was just a matter of the timestep being too large.  After decreasing the time step size, the trajectories are much more reasonable.